# How to create custom class with methods

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to create my own class for logging errors and messages to a database, but I'm new to creating custom classes and methods in Javascript. After plenty of research, I was able to put together the following code:

```
    function log ()
    {
    }

    log.error = function (currentFunction, logMessage)
    {
        createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
    }
```

And I'm able to call the `log.error` function successfully with:

```
    log.error("current function name", "this is my error message");
```

My question is this: Most of the sites I looked at said to organize your code like this instead:

```
    function log ()
    {
        this.error = function (currentFunction, logMessage)
        {
            createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
        }
    }
```

But whenever I try to call that error function, I get the following error:

> Cannot find function error in object function log(currentFunction, logMessage)

Does anyone know why this is? For the sake of keeping my code clean, I would really like to be able to place everything inside one function, but at this point it looks like I may have to separate everything out, as in the first code block above.

**EDIT - MY SOLUTION**

Thanks to both dystroy and Jose Vega (sorry Jose, I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer). I ended up using dystroy's solution simply because I feel it will be easier for me to maintain my code in the future, however Jose's answer helped give me insight into what I was trying to do and the different options available to me. I feel I have a much better grasp on what's going on when you do something like `var objectName = {}` vs `function className () {}`.

Here's my new code:

```
    function log ()
    {
        log.prototype.error = function (currentFunction, logMessage)
        {
            createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
        }

        log.prototype.warning = function (currentFunction, logMessage)
        {
            createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Warning");
        }

        log.prototype.info = function (currentFunction, logMessage)
        {
            createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Info");
        }

        function createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, messageType)
        {
            //code that updates MSSQL database
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using classes at all and your first function called `log` is totally useless as you call it.

You could have written it as

```
var log = {}

log.error = function (currentFunction, logMessage){
    createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
}
```

Usually, when you create a new function and want to see it as a class, you do like this :

```
function log () {
}
log.prototype.error = function (currentFunction, logMessage) {
    createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
}
```

And then you may use it like this :

```
(new log()).error("current function name", "this is my error message");
```

This looks a little like your second example, except that the `error` function is shared by all instances of `log` it you attach it to the prototype.

The MDN has [a document about the object model in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model).

Comment: +1 only one to mention `.prototype` when trying to implement classes in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the best way to organize that log "class", you can then do warn function and info function if you wanted.

```
var log = {
     error : function(currentFunction, logMessage) {
          createLog(currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
     },
     warn : function() {

     },
     info : function() {

     }
}
```

Comment: There is no class in this code but just a basic javascript object.

Comment: Hence the usage of the word class with quotes. I was merely trying to keep a consistency with the question's verbiage.

Comment: I couldn't vote up your answer, but it helped give me a better understanding of what I was doing, and ultimately helped me with the solution to my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write like this:

```
var log = {
    error: function (currentFunction, logMessage) {
        createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
    }
};
```

Then call it like this:

```
log.error("My function", "Is not working");
```

---

Although i usually write this using jQuery in the following fashion:

```
(function($) {

    //Declare object
    var _this = $.Log = new function () {

    };

    //Apply variables and methods
    $.extend(_this, {
        error: function (currentFunction, logMessage) {
            createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
        }
    });
)(jQuery);
```

This would later be called like this:

```
$.Log.error("My function", "Is not working");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the error() function can't be found is because it's inside the log object's constructor - the log() function is a constructor.  That's how you make private members in Javascript, put them in the constructor. To make your error() function visible, you need to attach it to the log object's prototype, like this.

```
function log ()
{
    log.prototype.error = function (currentFunction, logMessage)
    {
        createLog (currentFunction, logMessage, "Error");
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
var myLog = new log();
myLog.error("current function name", "this is my error message");
```

For a good article explaining public, private and protected members in javascript read this article: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html.